# Getting timeout error on xdmp:http-get

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to make an HTTP GET call in a script and keep getting a timeout error. I tried wrapping the call in `xdmp:log` to try and get more detailed info, but haven't gotten anything useful.

When I hit the endpoint from a browser, I have no problems. When I hit the endpoint going from my local to my test lanes, I have no problems. However, when I try to call from test to test, or local to local, I get the timeout.

Any suggestions on how I can better troubleshoot this?

Here is the error:

> SVC-SOCRECV: xdmp:http-get("http://my-domain-local.myorg.org:8080/api/publisher/apps") 
>       -- Socket receive error: wait 127.0.0.1:63078-127.0.0.1:8080: Timeout (decodeResponseLine1)

Comment: Have you tried applying the timeout option, to ensure that it waits a little longer than the default?

Comment: Yes, I doubled it to a 60 second timeout but it didn't change it. I am lead to believe it is a firewall issue, but won't be able to test it for a few days. I will add the answer when I find out though.

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue to me.  When you say "from test to test" and "from local to local", do you mean on the same machine?  If yes, have you tried to change the URL to use "127.0.0.1" or "localhost"?